# Как настроить слушателя SMS-сообщений на Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-development

Подскажите как реализовать приложение, которое будет прослушивать отправленные абонентом сообщения SMS.
Например: я отправляю SMS своему другу посредством стандартного приложения для отправки SMS, а данное сообщение транслируется в приложение на Flutter.